# Bypass angular 2 routing with a relative url

Tags: javascript, routes, angular5

I have googled a lot but cannot find a solution on this problem. I have a relative path like 'external/user/login/example.php' and I need in that case to bypass the angular routing to get my_env + relative_url.

Is that possible with angular? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you navigate to that URL with `RouterLink` or one of the `navigate` methods, no. You just navigate directly using the browser API, bypassing Angular:

```
window.location = ' /external/user/example.php';
```

Of course, you must make sure this route does not send you to the html document with the hosted Angular application. You might have to check your server's routing configuration for this.

Comment: I have tried this, but it always get catched by angular routing :(

Comment: When you do this, the browser is navigation to another url, so the only way Angular can catch it is if every URL in your web server redirects to the page containing your Angular app. Which server are you using? Are you launching the app with `ng serve`?

Comment: yes at moment I'm launching the app with ng serve. The problem for the moment is locally

Comment: Well, the server initiated with `ng serve` always redirects to `index.html`. Besides, you cannot use PHP with it. If you need to use PHP in the same server, you need another server technology and use it to serve both the PHP pages and the HTML pages with the Angular app

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, in your Angular Web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^bulletinboardapi/?" negate="true"/>
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />      
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Explanation

```
<match url="^bypassPath/?" negate="true"/> tag tells angular that if URL comes without /bypassPath/ then route as per angular.

www.yourwebsite.com/bypassPath/api/user/get will go to your API path (Server). In many cases bypassPath may be your virtual application pointing to your API project.

www.yourwebsite.com/login/ will route as per angular even if you refresh browser.
www.yourwebsite.com/home/ will route as per angular even if you refresh browser.
```

Hope this helps!